# Problems with Entity Framework and EntitiyDataSource

Tags: entity-framework-4, entitydatasource

I have simple scenario:

- Web Project(C#) with added dll reference to below DataSource project.
- Separate DataSource project (Class Library) where I added edmx file and generated POCOs with DbContext Generator.

Really, nothing special. I think every youtube instructional video I saw on Entity Framework is doing something simple.

What I discovered is that EntityDataSource simply doesn't work. I get range of error messages and I really can't see the pattern when they are showing up:

**Here are some:**
- Unable to load the specified metadata source
- Schema invalid and types cannot be loaded because the assembly contains EdmSchemaAttribute... loading by both name and attribute is not allowed.

Few time, don't know how, I managed to pass by this error, in that case I would get CLR error when I try to execute simple page with datasource and gridview (nothing was coded)

End to add to the problem...
I am referencing another DataSource project the same way. I am perfectly able to set this EntityDataSource without errors above. But when I click Refresh Schema, I get error "Could not find the CLR type for MyEntity.

What is wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the EdmSchemaAttribute error message, using EF 5.0 and WCF Data Services 5.2.0.  This was a data service using a `DbContext`-derived class, but the `DbContext`-derived class was in the same assembly as some EDMX files and ObjectContext-based code generated from the EDMX files.

The fix for me was to separate code-first EF code from model-first EF code (which uses ObjectContext and generates code with the `[EdmSchema]` attribute).  By moving the code-first code into a separate assembly, the error message went away and things are working.

I hope that helps.